# how to show as row_number() in codeignitier

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

need help what wrong with my code where this my sql command where successfull run in mysql :

```
SELECT func_inc_var_session() As row_number ,
                            vruasjalan2.*
                            FROM vruasjalan2  Where skid = @skid 
                 ORDER BY kategoriruasjalanid, subkategoriruasjalanid,ruasjalanid;"
```

but when i want to display in my controller row_number start error say"Call to undefined method Jalan_model::num_rows()"

```
public function ajax_list()
        {
            $list = $this->Jalan->get_datatables();
            $data = array();
            $no = $_POST['start'];
            foreach ($list as $Jalan) {
                $no++;
                $row = array();
                $row[] = $no;
                $row[] = $Jalan->row_number;
                $row[] = $Jalan->ruasjalanid;
                $row[] = $Jalan->skid;      
                $data[] = $row;
            }    
            $output = array(
                            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                            "recordsTotal" => $this->Jalan->count_all(),
                            "recordsFiltered" => $this->Jalan->count_filtered(),
                            "data" => $data,
                    );
            //output to json format
            echo json_encode($output);
        }

    }
```

and this is my model

```
public function get_list_companys()
    {
        $this->db->select('vruasjalan2.*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->order_by('kategoriruasjalanid','asc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();

        $companys = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) 
        {
            $companys[] = $row->kategoriruasjalanid;
        }
        return $companys;
    }
```

if there any expert know this problems

Comment: The error is about `num_rows()` and no call is shown to that method in your question. The problem is not in the code shown.